# Conditional Check in SQL WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to do a conditional statement in my where clause similar to

```
WHERE
IF(@Param = 0) THEN
Column1 != 7
```

I am attempting to allow the user to exclude a set of records based on the value of the @Param.

Comment: I suggest using <> rather than !=. The latter is more natural for C# programmers but is not part of the SQL standard. See here for my thoughts and some great discussion in the comments: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2008/03/20/which-to-use-or.aspx

Comment: I ended up using ((@Param = 0 AND Column1 != '24') OR (@Param = 1))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
Where (@Param = 0 And Column1 != 7)
```

If often do things like...

```
Where (@Param1 Is Null Or (Column1 = @Param1)) 
And   (@Param2 Is Null Or (Column2 = @Param2))
```

There's a good article about where clauses here...
http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2003/11/14/513.aspx

Answer (score 7):

You can combine these into a single condition:

```
WHERE
(@Param != 0 OR Column1 != 7)
```

For more complex conditions, you might also rely of CASE expressions (but noting that these are *expressions*, and must return a value, here `1` or (by default) `NULL`):

```
WHERE
    CASE WHEN @Param = 0 THEN
         CASE WHEN Column1 != 7 THEN 1 END
    WHEN @Param = 2 THEN
         CASE WHEN Column2 in (1,3,19) THEN 1 END
    END =  1
```

Comment: Good answer, I prefer using `CASE` myself since I find it a little easier to follow the logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE (@Param = 0 AND Column1 != 7) AND ...
```